# How to assure multiple guava caches do not lock each other?

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, locking, guava

It is my understanding, that Guava's Caches lock on a key by default. So if thread t1 and thread t2 both try to get the same key, only one will actually load it, while the other thread waits for the first one to get the value and gets the same one afterwards.

This is a very good default behaviour but it is not so optimal, if you're dealing with multiple caches that depend on each other.

We are in a Situation, where we have multiple cache instances and multiple threads. The threads query multiple caches to get their work done. Therefore, cache-instances depend on each other. It actually boils down to the following scenario:

Thread t1

```
Value v1 = cache1.get(k, new Callable<Value>() {
    Value call() {
        //do something
        Value v2 = cache2.get(k, doRealWorkCallable());
        Value v = calculateFrom(v2)
        return v;
    }
});
```

Thread t2

```
Value v2 = cache2.get(k, new Callable<Value>() {
    Value call() {
        //do something
        Value v1 = cache1.get(k, doRealWorkCallable());
        Value v = calculateFrom(v1)
        return v;
    }
});
```

If I understand the locking policy correctly, the above situation could result in a deadlock situation:
Thread t1 holds lock for k in cache1, waits for lock k in cache2.
Thread t2 holds lock for k in cache2, waits for lock k in cache1.

Is there any way guava allows to prevent this deadlock situation? As I see it, as long as you're using `CacheLoader` or `Callable`, you might end up in a deadlock situation, since both lock the key they are loading.

I think we could use the good old "check if present in cache, if not: calculate and put it there":

```
Value v1 = cache1.getIfPresent(k);
if (v1 == null) {
    //get it using cache2
    Value v2 = cache2.getIfPresent(k);
    if (v2 == null) {
        v2 = doRealWork();
        cache2.put(k,v2);
    }
    v1 = calculateFrom(v2);
    cache1.put(v1);
 }
```

(and of course the other way around for the second thread)

This comes with the cost of "maybe unneeded" calculations of the value(s) at the benefit of not risking deadlocked threads.

Is there any "better" way to do this with guava?

#### EDIT: a concrete example below

We are calling multiple webservices from an external system we cannot control. The data delivered by those webservices is hierarchical and linked by references. Example:

```
class WSOrganization {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    List<Integer> employeeIds; //like a collection of foreign keys
}
class WSEmployee {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Integer organizationId; //like a foreignkey
}
```

There are places where we need the employees and places where we need the organization. If we request the organization, we do so eagerly. If we fetch the employee, we also need the organization. The code is distributed between multiple service-stubs and so on, but in the end it all boils down to this:

```
//in EJB 1
PrefetchedOrganization getOrganization(Integer orgId) {
    WSOrganization org = orgService.getOrganizationById(orgId);
    for (Integer employeeId : org.employeeIds) {
        WSEmployee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
        listOfEmployees.add(employee);
    }
    return createPrefetchedOrgWithEmployees(org, listOfEmployees);
}

//in EJB 2
PrefetchedEmployee getEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
    WSEmployee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
    PrefetchedOrganization orgOfEmployee = ejb2.getOrganization(employee.organisationId);
    return orgOfEmployee.employee(employeeId);
}
```

Now, we would like to introduce caches here by using `javax.interceptor.Interceptor` on EJB 1 and EJB 2.

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext invocation) {
    Object object = getElementFromCache(invocation);
    return object;
}
```

It might happen that two threads call the two methods in opposite order and we definitely don't want them to block each other.

#### EDIT2: Example implementation of getElementFromCache() using Hashmaps

```
Integer id = idFrom(invocation);
if (cache.containsKey(id)) {
    return cache.get(id);
} else {
    Object result = invocation.proceed();
    cache.put(id, result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How can you possibly have mutually dependent values like this?  I'm not following how it could make sense in any application.

Comment: We are calling webservices of an external application and retrieve hierarchical data. I'll add a concrete example to the question.

Comment: Forget about Guava caches, how would you possibly do this normally?

Comment: Implementing the getElementFromCache() using hashmaps added to the question above (why can't one add code snippets to comments?).

Answer (score 0):

Guava does not seem to lock on a key when executing the Callable for a Cache. Otherwise the code you provided would always deadlock, e.g.:

```
getOrganization(1337):
    (contains employee X)
    getEmployee(x):
        getOrganization(1337) // deadlock by recursion!!!
```

The [documentation for Cache.get](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#get%28K,%20java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) states:

> This method provides a simple substitute for the conventional "if cached, return; otherwise create, cache and return" pattern.

Note that I have not tried this out, but just from the documentation Guava seems to err on the side of running your Callable multiple times.

In short, it's not a problem!